# How vue use getter setter on v-model?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="msg"/>
  <p>{{ msg }}</p>
</div>

<script>
class A{

}
A.a = 1
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  },
  computed: {
    msg: {
      cache: false,
      set: function(val){
            A.a = val
      },
      get: function(){
        return A.a   
      }
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

[run on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/750405/)

How vue use getter setter on v-model? I tried use getter and setter on v-model, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Your getters and setters are fine as is.  (They're not strictly necessary in this example, since they're not doing anything to modify the user input, but I assume that's a simplification for the purposes of your question.)

There are two separate issues with your code:

1. the input field is outside the Vue root node, so the framework can't see it.  [You corrected this in a late edit to the question.]
2. You're defining your data (`A.a`) outside of Vue, so the framework doesn't know to watch it for changes.

For the framework to be reactive to changes you must put the variable `A` in the `data` block of the component (and, if you really need an external variable, copy the updated value into it using the setter function).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    A: { a: 1 } // <-- your external variable, moved to where Vue can see it
  },
  computed: {
    msg: {
      set: function(val) {
        this.A.a = val;
        // If necessary, also copy val into an external variable here
      },
      get: function() {
        return this.A.a
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="msg" />
  <p>{{ msg }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `input` has to be inside the `#app` element. Yours is currently not even being watched by Vue instance.

```
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="msg"/>
  <p>{{ msg }}</p>
</div>
```

Also, your `A.a = 1` doesn't do anything. If you `console.log` A's value you won't see `a` anywhere. Instantiate A and add `a` variable in it's constructor:

```
class A {
    constructor(a) { this.a = a}
}
let myA = new A(0)
```

with Vue instance like this it will work:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    a: myA.a = 1
  },
  computed: {
    msg: {
      set: function(val) {
        this.a = val
      },
      get: function() {
        return this.a
      }
    }
  }
})
```

However, I'd move class instantiation to data:

```
data() {
    return {
        a: new A(1).a
    }
},
```

If you keep `a` outside of data your setter will work and update the value, but your getter will not since variables outside of Vue instance aren't being observed.

Answer (score 0):

The code to implement a model in vue is simple as:

```
var v1 = new Vue({
    el:'#vue1',
  data:{
    msg:'demo'
  }
});
```

And the html as:

```
<div id='vue1'>

<input type='text' v-model='msg' />
<p>
{{msg}}
</p>
</div>
```

The first problem is the scope. Since in your Vue instance you are providing the element id as `#app`, all the vue related markup should be inside an element with id `app`, in your case the div.

Second, the way you save the data, once you use `v-model` directive, it directly observes the changes in your model and make changes to the dom accordingly. You do not need the getter and setter methods.

Lastly, what was the code about the class A??
Please look into the the javascript manuals because it is well outside the scope of this question to explain all of that part in detail.
[Here is the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/750425/)